# When should parse() throw an error?

Tags: julia

I'm running interactively:

```
Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+1903
Commit 6b0fcce (2014-11-30 18:08 UTC)
```

From here in the docs for Base.parse:

http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=parse#Base.parse

I read this:

> If raise is true (default), syntax errors will raise an error;
>   otherwise, parse will return an expression that will raise an error
>   upon evaluation.

It works as documented when I do this:

```
julia> parse("end")
ERROR: ParseError("unexpected end")
```

But not when I do this:

```
julia> parse("println(")
:($(Expr(:incomplete, "incomplete: premature end of input")))
julia> eval(ans)
ERROR: syntax: incomplete: premature end of input
```

Is this expected behavior? Should `parse()` be throwing an error in this second case, or should it really wait until the `eval()`?

Comment: My initial guess is that this is a bug, or at the very least, the documentation should be improved. Would you mind opening an issue?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, posted it here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9505

Answer (score 1):

Parse should raise an error in this case. Per Simon Byrne's comment, I posted a GitHub issue which already has a pull request waiting to close it: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9514/

Thanks, everyone!